# LightGBM best iteration always return 1

Tags: python, lightgbm

I am using lightgbm for a regression problem, the following is my parameters :

```
lgbm_params = {
    'nthread': 5,
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'regression',
    'scale_pos_weight':7,
    'metric':['rmse',"l1"],
    'learning_rate': 0.001,
    'max_bin':2**7-1,
    'num_leaves': 63,
    'max_depth': -1,
    'subsample': 1,
    'feature_fraction': 0.9,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.08,
    'min_split_gain': 0.09,
    'lambda_l2' : 0.2,
    'verbose': 1,
}
```

with training parameters :

```
def lgb_mae_score(y_hat, data):
    y_true = data.get_label()
    return 'lgb_mae_score', mean_absolute_error(y_hat,y_true), True

dtrain = lgb.Dataset(train_x, label=train_y)
dval = lgb.Dataset(valid_x, label=valid_y, reference=dtrain)
bst = lgb.train(
    lgbm_params, dtrain, num_boost_round=20000,
    valid_sets=[dval], early_stopping_rounds=1000, verbose_eval=100,feval=lgb_mae_score
)
```

but my training process always stops at 1000 epoch and return this :

[image]

It is obvious that loss is still under decreasing and the first round is not the best iteration.

Any ideas why I got into this situation?

Any suggestions will be grateful.

---------------------------update----------------------------

I think the problem is caused by my custom metric function `lgb_mae_score`.

I remove it from train function and the training process goes well, but I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You set the early_stopping_rounds param in the model training. So it will stop at 1000 epoch.

Please refer the light-gbm doc:
https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.early_stopping.html.

Training will stop when there is a improvement in the model accuracy. If we set early_stopping_rounds param model will select the best param from the training data

Comment: I know, but when 1000 round reached, it should not stop because the loss is still under decreasing.

Comment: You instructed the algorithm to stop it even though the loss is still under decreasing after 1000 iterations. Please remove this param it will work fine

Comment: The document says `The model will train until the validation score stops improving`, I doubt the problems is caused by this parameter.

Comment: I removed `feval` parameter and keep `early_stopping_rounds` parameter, then training process goes well.

Comment: See here for the screenshot, https://imgur.com/3vdGgmQ
My training process stop at round 5200 because  since round 4256 my loss didn't improve anymore, so after 1000 round, the training process stoped.

Comment: Feval param is a evaluation function. In your image it is clearly mentioned, it stopped due to early stopping. Try with early_stopping_rounds param also to know the root cause